# Problem using selectInput to download multiple variables from data in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, download, reactive

I have a Shiny app that allows users to view polygon (chloropleth) maps in in leaflet. I would like to enable users to also download a csv of the data that is used in the map for variables that they have selected.

I have been able to use downloadHandler to download either a single variable or all of the data. I have not been able to download multiple selected variables. At present, when I use selectInput(multiple=TRUE) I receive an error.

I have searched online, and found that many people were having issues with filter by values within a variable but I wasn't able to find something of filtering a dataframe by multiple variables.

Here's a mre for my work (I've stripped out all of the leaflet code as it isn't really relevant here as that aspect is working well).

global.R

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

a <- c(1:10)
b <- c(21:30)
c <- runif(10)

data <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

ui.R

```
ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("download", "Download",
                  choices = c("A nice name for variable a",
                              "A nice name for variable b",
                              "A nice name for variable c"),
                  multiple = F),
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download selected variables")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("mytable")
    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
server <- (function(input, output, session) {

  decision <- reactive({
    switch(input$download,
           "A nice name for variable a"= data$a,
           "A nice name for variable b" = data$b,
           "A nice name for variable c" = data$c
           )
  })

  #Create download function for selected data
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {paste("SelectedVariables", ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {write.table(decision(), file, sep=",")
    }
  )

})
```

If I attempt to choose more than one variable I receive the following error:

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7180
Warning: Error in switch: EXPR must be a length 1 vector
  [No stack trace available]

I suspect it is the use of `switch` on the server side, but I wasn't sure what to use instead.

Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: Just to clarify, the mre above should work (in terms of downloading a single variable). To recreate the error I am receiving please replace line 

```multiple=F``` in the ui.R script with

```multiple=T```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `switch` I would recommend you to use named choices in your `selectInput`. Then you could get it working as in the example below. Note that this might need some error handling (e.g. no columns selected). Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

a <- c(1:10)
b <- c(21:30)
c <- runif(10)

data <- data.frame(a, b, c)

ui <-   sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("download", "Download",
                choices = c("A nice name for variable a" = "a",
                            "A nice name for variable b" = "b",
                            "A nice name for variable c" = "c"),
                multiple = T),
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download selected variables")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("mytable")
  )
)

server <- (function(input, output, session) {

  decision <- reactive({
    data[,input$download,drop=FALSE]
  })

  #Create download function for selected data
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {paste("SelectedVariables", ".csv", sep = "")},
    content = function(file) {write.table(decision(), file, sep=",")
    }
  )
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer Florian.

The code works well, and now I can download the variables as required.